# Source type if you don't know if it's a jpeg or gif

Tags: html, css

I have a list of images that I loop through, and then display as follows:

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcSet={"images/" + i.webpimage} />
    <source type="image/???" srcSet={"images/" + i.image} />
    <img src={"images/" + i.image} alt="image" />
</picture>
```

The challenge is that the image on the third line might be a jpeg but might also be a gif (this differs per `i`). What should I then fill in where I now have `???`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` options is not required, as from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source):

> **If the type attribute isn't specified**, the media's type is retrieved from the server and checked to see if the user agent can handle it; if it can't be rendered, the next  is checked. If the type attribute is specified, it's compared against the types the user agent can present, and if it's not recognized, the server doesn't even get queried; instead, the next  element is checked at once.

So, keep it empty, let the browser take care of it!